# pass value to php function argument by GET method

Tags: php, function, url-rewriting

I am trying to use a slug function with get method

I have a form with one input name="title" and use method="GET" . I am trying to supply title name to function argument but it is not working

Please tell me where is the problem 
 codes are here ...

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$title=$_GET['title'];
echo $title;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  function create_slug($string){
    $string = preg_replace( '/[«»""!?,.!@£$%^&*{};:()]+/', '', $string );
    $string = strtolower($string);
    $slug=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $string);
    return $slug;
  }
  $slug = create_slug($title);
  echo $slug;
}
?>
<form action="" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="title">
<input type="submit" value="convert">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance .....

Comment: The problem is that "not working" is not specific.

Comment: It looks like it should work to me. Are you getting any errors? You should be getting a notice about `Undefined index 'title'` when you open the page the first time -- that will only be set when you submit the form.

Comment: $_POST['submit'] is one problem, other is -> You don't have name="submit" in submit button which is why you are not able to get past `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` condition.

Answer (score 1):

use `$_GET['submit']` in place of `$_POST['submit']` as the method of your form is GET.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  ..
}
```

It will never evaluate as true, since you're using the method GET for the form.

You should change it to

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])) }
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the form method to 'GET', all parameters will be send in the url.
You can also set the method to 'POST', you can send more data through POST than GET, and it is a bit safer (an url may be logged on the webserver, with all it's parameters, so don't use GET for logins etc)

With 'isset()' you can check if the variable exists.

```
if(isset($_GET['title']))
{
    $slug = createSlug($_GET['title']);
    // Do something with this...
}
```

But make sure you fetch the input-field values from the correct method type (post or get)

```
<form method="POST" -> if(isset($_POST['title'])){ //... }
<form method="GET" ->  if(isset( $_GET['title'])){ //... }
```

A function to create a slug, (also strips beginning and ending '-' signs)

```
<?php
function createSlug($value)
{
   $slug = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $value);

   while(strlen($slug) > 0 && substr($slug, 0, 1) == '-') {
     $slug = substr($slug, 1);
   }
   while(strlen($slug) > 0 && substr($slug, -1) == '-') {
     $slug = substr($slug, 0, strlen($slug)-1);
   }
   return strtolower($slug);
}

// Example:
$title = " - My first PAGE Title!!! :)";
$slug = createSlug($title);

echo $slug;
// Output: my-first-page-title
```